# Explain probable typo in paper

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, optimal-control

I was just reading this paper here: [on PDE control.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220258951_Optimal_Bilinear_Control_of_an_Abstract_Schrodinger_Equation)

They start with a PDE: $$i \partial_t \psi(t,x) = (H_0- \mu(t))\psi(t,x)$$ which is their equation (1.1).

Then in (2.1) they say that by substituting $\psi(t,x)=\psi_1(t,x)+\psi_2(t,x)$ and(!) $\psi=(\psi_1,\psi_2)$ this PDE can be rewritten as the following systems

$$i \partial_t \psi_1(t,x) = (H_0- \mu(t))\psi_2(t,x)$$ 
$$i \partial_t \psi_2(t,x) = -(H_0- \mu(t))\psi_1(t,x).$$

I mean somehow it is clear that $\psi$ cannot be the sum of these two and the vector at the same time, but I thought that maybe somebody here understands what they might be doing from context which is why I am asking.

Comment: You have a typo (compared to the PDF): it's $\partial_t\psi_1$ and $\partial_t\psi_2$ not $i\partial_t\psi_1$ and $i\partial_t\psi_2$. Then it makes sense: we have $\partial_t(\psi_1 + i \psi_2) = (H_0 - \mu)(\psi_2-i\psi_1)$ so if $\psi = \psi_1 + i \psi_2$ then this says that $i\partial_t \psi = (H_0-mu)\psi$ which is (1.1).

Answer (score 1):

It's probably

$\psi(x,t) = \psi_1(x,t) + i \psi_2(x,t)$